# Contentful Query Content Types in PHP

Tags: php, contentful

I am very new to Contentful and trying to get all items of one particular content type "companies" from my Contentful database, but I get the error:

```
`400 Bad Request` response: { "sys": { "type": "Error", "id":
"InvalidQuery" }, "message": "The query you sent was invalid. Probably
a (truncated...) in
```

My code is:

```
$client = new Client($accessToken, $spaceID);
$query = new \Contentful\Delivery\Query();
$query->setContentType('hosting_companies');
$entries = $client->getEntries($query);
```

Does anybody know what I might be missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can get the whole response (not truncated) by catching the `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException` and calling `getResponse()->getBody()->getContents()` on it. Maybe it will give you a hint.

Answer (score 2):

I have found out the source of the problem: In Contentful we called the content type `hosting_companies`. Contentful turned that into `hostingCompanies` (CamelCase) and I didn't realise that. As soon as I changed the query, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% fluent in the php sdk but you query for the content type id 'hosting' and in the description you say 'companies'?

Looking at this example in the Contentful documentation the overall structure looks okay.

https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/content-type/query-entries/console/php